# What exercises can help my slightly concaved chest?

Tags: exercise, chest

I have a condition known as Pectus Excavatum, more commonly referred to as a sunken or concaved chest. I was not born with this - it has developed as I grew up, and is relatively minor when compared to photos you can see online. It is only somewhat noticeable now that I have begun weight lifting and developing more defined chest muscles.

However, something being only somewhat noticeable is still noticeable, and it bothers me. Are there are exercises I can do to fix the problem, or at least lessen how obvious it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few exercises I would recommend for such a problem.

Check these out:

- Chest Flys
- Incline Dumbell Press
- Bench Press
- Cable Crossovers

These suggestions are what worked for this guy, as well as some breathing exercises. I recommend you go check him out here:

http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=148765303

Good luck!

Comment: Why? What benefit would that provide for his problem? He already says he has defined chest muscles.

Comment: http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=148765303 It is just a suggestion based on what worked for this guy who had it. @SeanDuggan

Comment: :) In which case, edit that into your answer.